# dump out some tables of the database

Tags: sql, database, mysql

I am using **MySQL** v5.1 on **Ubuntu** machine.

I have a database named `db_test` which contain tables like `cars`, `customers`, `departments`, `prices`  , and so on.

I know I can use the following commands to **dump out** the `db_test` database and **dump** the database **back** into a new database in following way:

```
mysqldump -u username -p -v db_test > db_test.sql
mysqladmin -u username -p create new_database
mysql -u username -p new_database < db_test.sql
```

But for my `new_database` , I **only needs some tables from** `db_test` database, **not all the tables**.

So, How can I dump out some tables from `db_test` database and dump these tables back to my `new_database` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use below code:

```
mysqldump -u username -p -v db_test[table1, table2,....] > db_test.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html):

```
shell> mysqldump [options] db_name [tbl_name ...]
```

List the names of the tables after the database name; listing no table names results in all tables being dumped.

Answer (score 0):

Simply list the tables in the mysqldump command.